# Add a Specific Time to a Date Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date

I have a stored procedure that receives a date value like this:

```
@AsOf date
```

In the query I am using this date to filter a **datetime** field. I need to convert the **date** passed in to a **datetime** field with the time portion set to *09:00:00 PM* so I can add a filter in the WHERE clause like this:

```
(DateCreated < @TimeAsOfNinePM)
```

I know this is easy, but it's just escaping me at the moment. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
DECLARE @TimeAsOfNinePM datetime 
DECLARE @AsOf date
SET @AsOf = '2010-10-01'
SET @TimeAsOfNinePM = dateadd(hh,21, cast(@AsOf as datetime)) 

PRINT @TimeAsOfNinePM
```

The trick is you need to convert the `date` datatype to a `datetime` datatype to add hours to it.